# Convert Character (HH:MM) to Minutes

Tags: r, time, character

I've spent a few hours reading various packages documentation, but am still stumped (coming back to using R after a few years away).

I have time data of class character in my data frame e.g. 03:30

How can I convert this to minutes ? i.e. 03:30 goes to 210

Any ideas?

Many thanks indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be

```
library(lubridate)
as.numeric(hm(str1)) /60
#[1] 210
```

Or specifically convert to seconds with `period_to_seconds` and divide by 60

```
period_to_seconds(hm(str1))/60
#[1] 210
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "03:30"
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Convert to second works for me :) much appreciated.